# dplyr: max value in a group, excluding the value in each row?

Tags: r, dplyr, greatest-n-per-group

I have a data frame that looks as follows:

```
> df <- data_frame(g = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'), x = c(7, 3, 5, 9, 2, 4))
> df
Source: local data frame [6 x 2]

  g x
1 A 7
2 A 3
3 B 5
4 B 9
5 B 2
6 C 4
```

I know how to add a column with the maximum `x` value for each group `g`:

```
> df %>% group_by(g) %>% mutate(x_max = max(x))
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: g

  g x x_max
1 A 7     7
2 A 3     7
3 B 5     9
4 B 9     9
5 B 2     9
6 C 4     4
```

But what I would like is to get is the maximum `x` value for each group `g`, *excluding the `x` value in each row*.

For the given example, the desired output would look like this:

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: g

  g x x_max x_max_exclude
1 A 7     7             3
2 A 3     7             7
3 B 5     9             9
4 B 9     9             5
5 B 2     9             9
6 C 4     4            NA
```

I thought I might be able to use `row_number()` to remove particular elements and take the max of what remained, but hit warning messages and got incorrect `-Inf` output:

```
> df %>% group_by(g) %>% mutate(x_max = max(x), r = row_number(), x_max_exclude = max(x[-r]))
Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
Groups: g

  g x x_max r x_max_exclude
1 A 7     7 1          -Inf
2 A 3     7 2          -Inf
3 B 5     9 1          -Inf
4 B 9     9 2          -Inf
5 B 2     9 3          -Inf
6 C 4     4 1          -Inf
Warning messages:
1: In max(c(4, 9, 2)[-1:3]) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
2: In max(c(4, 9, 2)[-1:3]) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In max(c(4, 9, 2)[-1:3]) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

What is the most {readable, concise, efficient} way to get this output in dplyr? Any insight into why my attempt using `row_number()` doesn't work would also be much appreciated. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is this code:summarise(group_by(df,g),max.x=max(x))?

Comment: Thanks, @Shenglin Chen, but that doesn't match the desired output in the above example. That gives me the maximum `x` value for each group (returning a data_frame with 3 rows). But what I want is a data_frame with the same number of rows as the input table, where the value at row `r` gives the maximum `x` value in group `g`, excluding row `r`. See the "desired output" above for a concrete example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(g) %>% 
  arrange(desc(x)) %>% 
  mutate(max = ifelse(x == max(x), x[2], max(x)))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
#Groups: g
#
#  g x max
#1 A 7   3
#2 A 3   7
#3 B 9   5
#4 B 5   9
#5 B 2   9
#6 C 4  NA
```

---

**Benchmark**

I've tried the solutions so far on the benchmark:

```
df <- data.frame(g = sample(LETTERS, 10e5, replace = TRUE),
                 x = sample(1:10, 10e5, replace = TRUE))

library(microbenchmark)

mbm <- microbenchmark(
  steven = df %>% 
    group_by(g) %>% 
    arrange(desc(x)) %>% 
    mutate(max = ifelse(x == max(x), x[2], max(x))),
  eric = df %>% 
    group_by(g) %>% 
    mutate(x_max = max(x), 
           x_max2 = sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[2], 
           x_max_exclude = ifelse(x == x_max, x_max2, x_max)) %>% 
    select(-x_max2),
  arun = setDT(df)[order(x), x_max_exclude := c(rep(x[.N], .N-1L), x[.N-1L]), by=g],
  times = 50
)
```

@Arun's data.table solution is the fastest:

```
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval cld
#  steven 158.58083 163.82669 197.28946 210.54179 212.1517 260.1448    50  b 
#    eric 223.37877 228.98313 262.01623 274.74702 277.1431 284.5170    50   c
#    arun  44.48639  46.17961  54.65824  47.74142  48.9884 102.3830    50 a
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Interesting problem. Here's one way using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)[order(x), x_max_exclude := c(rep(x[.N], .N-1L), x[.N-1L]), by=g]
```

The idea is to *order* by column `x` and on those indices, we group by `g`. Since we've the ordered indices, for the first `.N-1` rows, the max value is the value at `.N`. And for the `.N`th row, it's the value at `.N-1`th row.

`.N` is a special variable that holds the number of observations in each group.

I'll leave it to you and/or the `dplyr` experts to translate this (or answer with another approach).

Comment: Thanks for the data.table version, @Arun. I think that is similar in spirit to my best dplyr solution so far (which I also just posted), although I don't know my data.table well enough to say whether they are identical.

Comment: Eric, similar idea, but not the implementation. You're calling `sort()` for each group, and then there's the `ifelse()`...

Answer (score 2):

This is the best I've come up with so far. Not sure if there's a better way.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(g) %>% 
  mutate(x_max = max(x), 
         x_max2 = sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[2], 
         x_max_exclude = ifelse(x == x_max, x_max2, x_max)) %>% 
  select(-x_max2)
```

Comment: You could simplify to: `group_by(df, g) %>% mutate(max = ifelse(x == max(x), sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[2], max(x)))`

Answer (score 1):

Another way with a functional:

```
df %>% group_by(g) %>% mutate(x_max_exclude = max_exclude(x))
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: g

  g x x_max_exclude
1 A 7             3
2 A 3             7
3 B 5             9
4 B 9             5
5 B 2             9
6 C 4            NA
```

We write a function called `max_exclude` that does the operation that you describe.

```
max_exclude <- function(v) {
  res <- c()
  for(i in seq_along(v)) {
    res[i] <- suppressWarnings(max(v[-i]))
  }
  res <- ifelse(!is.finite(res), NA, res)
  as.numeric(res)
}
```

It works with `base R` too:

```
df$x_max_exclude <- with(df, ave(x, g, FUN=max_exclude))
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]

  g x x_max_exclude
1 A 7             3
2 A 3             7
3 B 5             9
4 B 9             5
5 B 2             9
6 C 4            NA
```

## Benchmark

Here's a lesson kids, beware of for loops!

```
big.df <- data.frame(g=rep(LETTERS[1:4], each=1e3), x=sample(10, 4e3, replace=T))


microbenchmark(
  plafort_dplyr = big.df %>% group_by(g) %>% mutate(x_max_exclude = max_exclude(x)),
  plafort_ave = big.df$x_max_exclude <- with(big.df, ave(x, g, FUN=max_exclude)),
  StevenB = (big.df %>% 
    group_by(g) %>% 
    mutate(max = ifelse(row_number(desc(x)) == 1, x[row_number(desc(x)) == 2], max(x)))
    ),
  Eric = df %>% 
    group_by(g) %>% 
    mutate(x_max = max(x), 
           x_max2 = sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[2], 
           x_max_exclude = ifelse(x == x_max, x_max2, x_max)) %>% 
    select(-x_max2),
  Arun = setDT(df)[order(x), x_max_exclude := c(rep(x[.N], .N-1L), x[.N-1L]), by=g]
)

Unit: milliseconds
          expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval
 plafort_dplyr 75.219042 85.207442 89.247409 88.203225 90.627663 179.553166   100
   plafort_ave 75.907798 84.604180 87.136122 86.961251 89.431884 104.884294   100
       StevenB  4.436973  4.699226  5.207548  4.931484  5.364242  11.893306   100
          Eric  7.233057  8.034092  8.921904  8.414720  9.060488  15.946281   100
          Arun  1.789097  2.037235  2.410915  2.226988  2.423638   9.326272   100
```

Comment: This seems quite expensive. Not sure this could scale for larger data set.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré it could be. It was just another idea.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré I tested the speeds. Embarrassingly slow.

Comment: It seems that you didn't use "big.df" in some of the benchmarks (Eric, and Arun) ?